# Como mostrar dados de tabela relacionada de forma organizada por tópicos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com uma dúvida em SQL que é a seguinte: Tenho duas tabelas, a tabela pai, e a tabela filha, onde a tabela filha recebe o `id` da tabela pai como chave estrangeira, porém, não sei como mostrar os dados inseridos de forma organizada. Preciso que os dados apareçam na tela da seguinte forma:

> Titulo 1 da tabela pai: Dado 1 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da
>   tabela pai Dado 2 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da tabela pai
>   Dado 3 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da tabela pai
>
> Título 2 da tabela pai: Dado 1 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 2 da
>   tabela pai Dado 2 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 2 da tabela pai

E assim por diante, porém, os meus dados estão aparecendo na tela da seguinte forma na tela:

> Título 1 da tabela pai: Dado 1 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da
>   tabela pai
>
> Título 1 da tabela pai: Dado 2 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da
>   tabela pai
>
> Título 1 da tabela pai: Dado 3 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 1 da
>   tabela pai
>
> Título 2 da tabela pai: Dado 1 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 2 da
>   tabela pai
>
> Título 2 da tabela pai: Dado 1 da tabela filha relacionado ao id 2 da
>   tabela pai

O select está mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM pai
LEFT JOIN filha ON (pai.id_tabelaPai = filha.id_tabelaPai)
```

Comment: O select tem que ser sobre a tabela filha, conectando-a com a tabela pai. De outro modo o resultado repetirá cada registro pai tantas vezes quantas existirem registros filhos (cada pai com 3 filhos será exibido 3 vezes). Inverta a sua query - troque "pai" e "filha" de lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que me parece, você está buscando os dados da forma correta mas está usando um único *loop* para percorrê-los. Você precisa de um *loop* externo para percorrer os dados e *loops* internos para percorrer os dados da tabela filha até uma certa condição de parada.

Nesse exemplo a condição de parada é o id (ou qualquer outro dado que você queira, como por exemplo o título) da tabela pai:

```
<?php

$resultSet = [
    [ 'id_pai' => 1, 'id_filha' => 1 ],
    [ 'id_pai' => 1, 'id_filha' => 2 ],
    [ 'id_pai' => 1, 'id_filha' => 3 ],
    [ 'id_pai' => 2, 'id_filha' => 4 ],
    [ 'id_pai' => 2, 'id_filha' => 5 ]
];

if (sizeof($resultSet) > 0) {
    $idTabelaPai = $resultSet[0]['id_pai'];
    echo 'tabela pai   = ' . $idTabelaPai . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'tabela filha = ' . $resultSet[0]['id_filha'] . PHP_EOL;
    for ($i=1, $count=sizeof($resultSet); $i<$count; $i++) {
        if ($resultSet[$i]['id_pai'] !== $idTabelaPai) {
            $idTabelaPai = $resultSet[$i]['id_pai'];
            echo 'tabela pai   = ' . $idTabelaPai . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo 'tabela filha = ' . $resultSet[$i]['id_filha'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
tabela pai   = 1
tabela filha = 1
tabela filha = 2
tabela filha = 3
tabela pai   = 2
tabela filha = 4
tabela filha = 5
```

Para que a solução acima funciona, é necessário ordenar os resultados primeiro pelo id da tabela pai, e então pelos ids da tabela filha:

```
ORDER BY pai.id, filha.id
```

Comment: Correto! Excelente explicação.